# Pointers of pointer and pass by reference

Tags: c, pass-by-reference, pointer-to-pointer

I'm struggling to understand how pointers work.
The way I got it is that, when I declare a pointer to, say, int, I create both a variable that'll contain an address (that must be initialized to even operate on the int) and an int variable. Visually, I'd represent this this way (address;int). For example, if I declared

```
int* number;
```

I'd have "number" being the address variable and "*number" being the int variable.

Likewise, declaring something such as int** d should mean to create a pointer to (address;int). That'd be [address;(address;int)].

With this in mind, I was trying to modify the int value of **d by using an external function, incrementer_3, and this so called pass by reference, but I get an error on runtime. So, I was wondering what I'm missing.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void incrementer(int* a) {
    (*a)++;
}

void incrementer_2(int** a) {
    (**a)++;
}

void incrementer_3(int*** a) {
    (***a)++;
}

int main() {
    int b = 7;
    incrementer(&b);
    printf("%d\n", b);

    int* c = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *c = 4;
    incrementer_2(&c);
    printf("%d\n", *c);

    int** d = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*));
    **d = 6;
    incrementer_3(&d);
    printf("%d\n", **d);

    system("pause");
}
```

FYI the part when I increase b and c works fine.
On a side note, I was also wondering if it's possible to modify the value of *c by using the function "incrementer" and not "incrementer_2". In fact I was just thinking that I could have simply written from main

```
incrementer(&(*c));
```

or, in a simpler way

```
incrementer(c);
```

but none of them work on runtime.

Comment: `**d = 6;` - this invokes undefined behaviour.  You haven't initialised `*d`.

Comment: Why not simply `int *c = &b;` and `int **d = &c;`?

Comment: Also note that C doesn't have "pass by reference", it can only be *emulated* through the use of pointers and the address-of operator.

Comment: Lastly, with both your way and my way, doing e.g. `incrementer(c)` should work fine (if, as in your current code, you have properly initialized `c`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude about the "pass by reference": in fact I've just used the terminology I've found in my teacher's slides.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude about the last point: exactly, I apologize because that piece of code was actually correct. For some reason I thought it wasn't compiling the way it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep in mind that a pointer need not actually refer to anything, and even if it does refer to something that something need not be valid. Keeping track of those things is your job as a programmer.

By convention an invalid pointer will be given the value 0 (which is what NULL eventually comes to) but that is only convention, other values might be used in some circumstances.

So, with "int* number;" you have declared a pointer-to-int but because it is not initialized you have absolutely no idea what value it contains, dereferencing it at this point is undefined behavior - meaning that most anything *could* happen if you tried doing so, though in reality it will likely simply crash your program.

The problem with:

```
int** d = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*));
    **d = 6;
```

is that while d is initialized *d is not. You could do:

```
*d = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

or

```
 *d = c;
```

but *d needs to be pointed at something before you can use **d.

Comment: Thank you, the idea is clear and the program works now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you allocate memory for the `int*` but you don't allocate any memory for the `int` or set the pointer of the `int`.
Should be:

`int** d = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*));
*d = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
**d=6;`

> The way I got it is that, when I declare a pointer to, say, int, I create both a variable that'll contain an address (that must be initialized to even operate on the int) and an int variable.

No, when you declare a pointer you create a variable that knows how to contain an address. When you use `malloc()` you allocate memory. `malloc()` returns an address that you may assign to your pointer.

P.S. - `incrementer(c)` should work just fine

Comment: Thank you, it does work now.
About the last point, I improperly meant that I've assumed that declaring a pointer to int means to create a variable that has two fields, one for containing an address, the other for containing an int value.
Is this guess even true?

Comment: You're welcome. No, a pointer contains only one value - an address. You may use operators like `* . ->` to handle the value in the memory address pointed by the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

```
int b
```

`b` is an `int`. We can refer to it by writing `b`.

```
b = 7;
```

Here we assign a number to `b`.

```
int* c
```

`c` is a pointer that should point to an `int`. We can refer to that `int` by writing `*c`.

```
c = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

We have found a piece of memory that can hold an `int`, and made a pointer that points to that piece, and assigned it to `c`. All is well.

```
*c = 4;
```

Here we assign a number to `*c`. See? `*c` behaves just like `b`. But that's only because we have initialised it with a valid pointer! Without that, `*c = 4;` would be invalid.

```
int** d
```

`d` is a pointer that should point to a thing of type `int*`, which we can refer to by writing `*d`. That `int*` thing, in turn, should point to an `int`, which we can refer to by writing `**d`.

```
d = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*));
```

We have found a piece of memory that can hold an `int*`, and made a pointer that points to that piece, and assigned it to `d`. All is well. Now that `int*` we call `*d`, what does it point to?

Nothing. In order to point it to something, we could have found a piece of memory that can hold an `int`, and made a pointer that points to that piece, and assigned it to our `*d`, just as we have done earlier with `c`. See? `*d` behaves just like `c`. In order to use `*c` we had to initialise `c` with a valid pointer first. In order to use `**d` we need to initialise `*d` with a valid pointer first.

```
*d = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```